# Spring API Rest Basic Auth SecurityConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Primero de todo decir que estoy empezando con SpringBoot.

Estoy utilizando las dependecias:

- JPA
- WEB
- MySQL
- Security

Estoy haciendo una API Rest e integrando Basic Auth.
Se que **NoOpPasswordEncoder** está **deprecated**, pero como he dicho estoy empezando.

Mi problema es que a los endpoints que se suponen que deberían ser accesibles con Auth Basic y si hago una request normal a ese endpoint me devuelve la  información. Pero no debería ser así, ya que le estoy diciendo que para ese endpoint solo puede acceder el ADMIN o el USER.

Hago las request mediante POSTMAN.

Sin Auth Basic:
`GET localhost:8080/api/teacher/findAll` -> Devuelve info. Bien.

`GET localhost:8080/api/teacher/admin/findAll` -> Devuelve info. Mal: Debería decirme que no se puede acceder porque necesitaría user y passsword.

`GET localhost:8080/api/teacher/user/findAll` -> Develve info. Mal: Debería decirme que no se puede acceder porque necesitaría user y passsword.

Este es mi código y ante todo gracias por la ayuda que podais aportar.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ProfesorController {

    @Autowired
    IProfesorService profesorService;

    @GetMapping("/teacher/findAll")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>> listAllProfesores() {
        List<Profesor> profesores = profesorService.findAllProfesor();
        if (profesores.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>>(profesores, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/teacher/admin/findAll")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>> listAllProfesoresAdmin() {
        List<Profesor> profesores = profesorService.findAllProfesor();
        if (profesores.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>>(profesores, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/teacher/user/findAll")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>> listAllProfesoresUser() {
        List<Profesor> profesores = profesorService.findAllProfesor();
        if (profesores.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Profesor>>(profesores, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("password1").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user2").password("password2").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/teacher/findAll").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/teacher/admin/findAll").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/teacher/user/findAll").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("*/create/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a iokerhe por la ayuda.

El error está en la configuracion de HttpSecurity.

iokerhe:

"No estás poniendo bien las reglas de seguridad. Las URIs no empiezan por "/api".
En tu controlador, en la clase, tienes esta anotación: @RequestMapping("/api")
Eso significa que todo endpoint que contenga ese controlador va a responder a través de "/api/loquesea".
Como no estás poniendo ese inicio en las reglas de seguridad, y no has cerrado el resto, te las pasa siempre."

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER")
        .and().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/teacher/findAll").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/teacher/admin/findAll").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/api/teacher/user/findAll").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("*/create/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```